# How to use Ghostscript without opening shell?

Tags: windows, shell, ghostscript

Using `gswin32c.exe` on Windows 7, and starting next command from a `.bat`-file, I can convert a pdf to a image using ghostscript. However, the shell is

a) opened and

b) not closed after finishing.

```
C:\Users\me\desktop\gswin32c.exe -dQuiet -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r200 -sOutputFile=C:\Users\me\desktop\converted.jpg C:\Users\me\desktop\test.pdf
```

How can I call this command silently in the background, without showing the shell?

Ultimately, I want to use this command from a Qt-application without a `bat`-file. There I am using `QProcess` to execute the command, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Ghostscript API and simply load the DLL.

The only way, under Windows, to run the supplied binary without a command shell that I'm aware of is to make it a service and schedule it. In any event I think its a bad idea, as your user can be left with Ghostscript executing and having to use Task Manager to kill it. (which they won't do, because they don't realise its running....)

NB you haven't set -dBATCH, which means that Ghostscript is still executing (ie its **not** finished, its waiting for more input from you). If you do that I believe you will find that the window will close after completion.

Comment: In the meantime I also figured out that `-dBATCH` does indeed close the window after finishing. Thanks.

I noticed that if run from my application, somehow the shell does not even open any more, so everything is ok.